# By modifying arr[1][0] multiple cells are modified

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make a match-3 game (candy crush like). I have an object `level` which has `tiles` property which is a 2d array. After I do some manipulations I want to change the type of a specific element to `-1` using this simple line (I'll be using `for`, but for now I've made it simple for demonstrative purposes)

`level.tiles[1][0].type = -1;`

Here is the code

```
var level = {
    x: 250,         // X position
    y: 113,         // Y position
    columns: 8,     // Number of tile columns
    rows: 8,        // Number of tile rows
    tilewidth: 40,  // Visual width of a tile
    tileheight: 40, // Visual height of a tile
    tiles: [],      // The two-dimensional tile array
    selectedtile: {selected: false, column: 0, row: 0}
};

var tileTypes = [
    {
        type: "red",
        colors: [255, 128, 128]
    },
    {
        type: "green",
        colors: [128, 255, 128]
    },
    {
        type: "darkBlue",
        colors: [128, 128, 255]
    },
    {
        type: "yellow",
        colors: [255, 255, 128]
    }
];
function createLevel() {
    for (var i = 0; i < level.columns; i++) {
        level.tiles[i] = [];
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < level.columns; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < level.rows; j++) {
            level.tiles[i][j] = getRandomTile();
        }
    }
}

function getRandomTile() {
    return tileTypes[Math.floor(Math.random() * tileTypes.length)];
}

createLevel();
level.tiles[1][0].type = -1;
```

Unfortunately not only `tiles[1][0]` is modified, but multiple cells. The interesting part is that every time random cells are affected

Comment: That is because objects are copied using reference. So when you do `var x = typeTiles[0]; var y = tileTypes[0]`, both hold reference to same object. And modification in one will change both

Comment: @Rajesh Typo: objects are **not** copied but linked.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because `getRandomTile()` returns a *reference* to a tile type, not a copy of it.

I.e. to simplify this case:

```
var a = {x: 1};
var b = [a, a, a, a];
b[0].x = 2;
console.log(a, b);
```

will output

```
{x: 2} [{x: 2}, {x: 2}, {x: 2}, {x: 2}]
```

If you want the tiles to be modifiable, have `getRandomTile` return a copy – a shallow copy in this case, so `colors` is still a reference, not a copy – of the randomly chosen tile type.

```
function getRandomTile() {
    const tileType = tileTypes[Math.floor(Math.random() * tileTypes.length)];
    // Idiom for shallow copy, i.e. assign all properties of tileType
    // into a new, unique object.
    return Object.assign({}, tileType);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you modify the type object, instead of linking to another type. A solution would be to clone it when creating the tiles:

```
function getRandomTile() {
    var srcType = tileTypes[Math.floor(Math.random() * tileTypes.length)];
    return {type:srcType.type, colors:srcType.color};
}
```

Another one (depending on your goal) would be to have Tile objects, each one having a reference to a Type object (not just an integer). At this point some classes might be helpful:

```
class TileType {
   constructor(colors){
       this.colors = colors;
   }
}
let tileTypes = [...]

class Tile {
    constructor(){
        this.type = tileTypes[Math.random()*tileTypes.length|0];
    }
    setNewType(type){
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by `getRandomTile` which returns the same reference of the `object` defined in `tileTypes` if the index passed in is the same. You can print `tileTypes` to help your understand what happens.